# Ошибка при запуске eclipse (.log)

Tags: eclipse, логирование

Здравствуйте, помогите решить проблему, установил Visual Editor для Eclipse Mars 4.5, перезапустил и вылетела ошибка с указанием на логовский файл.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-03-23 15:33:52.222
!MESSAGE Ошибка приложения
!STACK 1
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.BindingTable.addBinding(Lorg/eclipse/jface/bindings/Binding;)V" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/e4/ui/workbench/swt/util/BindingProcessingAddon, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/eclipse/e4/ui/bindings/internal/BindingTable, have different Class objects for the type org/eclipse/jface/bindings/Binding used in the signature
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon.defineBinding(BindingProcessingAddon.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon.defineBindingTable(BindingProcessingAddon.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon.defineBindingTables(BindingProcessingAddon.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon.init(BindingProcessingAddon.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:898)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Comment: Eclipse постоянно какие-нибудь ошибки выплевывает. Если желаемый функционал работает, забейте на них. Для GUI обычно используют [WindowBuilder](https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/)

Comment: Вот именно, что эта ошибка мешает запуску Eclipse

Comment: Попробуйте запустить Eclipse в clean mode: это можно сделать либо запустив его из командной строки `eclipse.exe -clean`, либо добавив строку `-clean` в eclipse.ini. Если запуcтится, снесите плагин. Если не запустится, я бы переустановил Eclipse - там забот на 10 минут. Как я уже сказал, используйте WindowBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Очень похоже на проблема с Babel. У вас случайно он не установлен? Если установлен не забыли-ли добавить аргумент запуска ***-nl ru***. Если установлен попробуйте запустить с ***-nl en***

Comment: не помогло(((((